# WPF DataGrid User Control with Enum Property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid UserControl with enum property.

```
    public List<myEnum> dataList = new List<myEnum>();
    public enum myEnum
    {

        Info,
        Error,
        Warning,
        Debug,
        Success
    }
```

I want to expose this property to the MainWindow where the usercontrol will be hosted. So that I can access it in code like..

```
        dataGrid1.dataList.Add(logDataGrid1.myEnum.Info);
        dataGrid1.dataList.Add(logDataGrid1.myEnum.Warning);
        dataGrid1.dataList.Add(logDataGrid1.myEnum.Success);
```

Please advise. Or whether any alternative solution for this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers!
I found the answer.

Public enum in your usercontrol can be accessed by **Namespace.Class.PublicEnumName**

**Ex)**
    WpfControlLibrary1.UserDataGrid.myEnum.Info

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
    IEnumerable<myEnum> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum))
                                .OfType<myEnum>()
                                .ToList();
```

Don't name your enum Type, it conflicts with 'System.Type'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to access the enum to code where the usercontrol will be used, not in the usercontrol code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public enum mytype 
{

    Info,
    Error,
    Warning,
    Debug,
    Success
}

public List<mytype> lst = Enum.GetValues(typeof(mytype))
                              .Cast<mytype>().ToList();
```